# Obj-C/Cocoa instance/pointers/properties Need help understanding an example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to pick up Obj-C and iPhone dev after a long break and so I'm re-reading Apress's Beginning iPhone 3 Development.

Now, I'm struggling to get my head around the following:

```
#import "BlueViewController.h"
```

....

```
@synthesize blueViewController;
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    BlueViewController *blueController = [[BlueViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];

    self.blueViewController = blueController;

    [self.view insertSubview:blueController.view atIndex:0];

    //Why don't we use the following instead of the above?
    //[self.view insertSubview:self.blueViewController.view atIndex:0]?

    [blueController release];
    [superViewDidLoad];
}
```

It seems more logical to me that, since we just assigned blueController to self.blueViewController, we should use the latter rather than the former. What's the reasoning behind the example? What's wrong with my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to clarity. Write the code that you find most readable.

I tend towards:

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) BlueViewController *blueController;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize blueController=_blueController;
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _blueController = [[BlueViewController alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.blueController.view atIndex:0];
    [superViewDidLoad];
}
```

That `_` helps me helps me keep track of direct variable access (_blueController) versus access as a property (self.blueController).

Comment: It certainly reads better. Would the following work the same way? [self.view insertSubview:_blueController.view atIndex:0];

Comment: Yes. _blueController and self.blueController are exactly the same in this case, as I'm not overriding the accessor methods. Setting the value directly versus using the accessor is not equivalent though. Direct setting doesn't add a retain and doesn't trigger KVO.

Answer (score 2):

They're both pointing to the same reference. No difference, really. Your approach works as well.

Comment: Is there any difference in the retain count?

Comment: The retain count should go up to 2 when it's assigned to self.blueViewController (assuming the default behavior hasn't been overridden). It'll go down to 1 when the controller is released at the end of the method scope.